# Angular 4: stopPropagation() works, but also stops any further DOM update

Tags: angular

I have a `<table>` of users. Each `<tr>` can be clicked to open an information panel with the details of the user. Clicking it again closes the panel.

```
<tr (click)="data.info = invert(data.info);">
```

The `<tr>` also has icons to modify or delete the user. These are in separate `<td>`s.

```
<td (click)="delete(data?._id, rowIndex); $event.stopPropagation();">
```

The problem is when I click the modify or delete icons, the `<tr>`'s `(click)` event also fires. Yep, this can be easily solved by adding `$event.stopPropagation()` to the function I call. But interestingly it stops not only the parent element's click event from firing, but also any other action in the DOM.

The function invoked when clicking the delete icon is simply changing a variable which should cause a confirmation box (which is a `div`) to appear by `ngIf`. The variable indeed changes, but the `div` doesn't appear, only after I click the icon a second time. Interestingly though, it also works if for the second time I click anywhere on the screen.

The same happens even if the `<tr>` has no `(click)` action.

It doesn't help if I move `stopPropagation()` to the `delete` function I invoked, and it doesn't matter where I put it in the function.

The question is if I am using the proper way to stop propagation when clicking the `<td>`?

Answer (score 4):

OK, I found it. This is something others may run into, and I haven't found any solution to this.

The root of the problem was that the component which I was trying to display by changing a variable in my `delete()` function was a `@ViewChild`. The problem did not occur with any other component or plain DOM element.

The solution was simply adding a `ChangeDetectorRef` to the parent component's `constructor` and put this to the end of the `delete()` function:

```
this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: For anyone else who didn't know, ChangeDetectorRef is part of angular/core so the relevant component requires the following reference at the top: import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add simply this:

```
(contextmenu)=" false"
```

or if you want to call a function:

```
(contextmenu)="click(); false"
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are clicking on the td and calling the delete() method. You should stop the propagation in the delete method.

ex:

```
delete():void{event.stopPropagation(); //rest lines of codes}
```

try this and remove the propagation from the template. It should solve the issue.

Comment: Nope, this didn't help.

Comment: I checked with a simple table having tr and td and this worked. In your case then it should be something else.

Comment: That's exactly what I think... though maybe not.

Comment: Yes, it works if the variable only displays a plain DOM element like a div. But in fact it's supposed to display a component, which has a ViewChild decorator. This may be the problem, because other elements without ViewChild work too.